# Why I get this error while trying to make post request to a server in iOS Swift: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value?

Tags: ios, swift, post, request, alamofire

```
 func uploadImage(var image:UIImage)
{
    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([.Encoding64CharacterLineLength]) 
    let parameters = [
        "img": base64String
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, API_URL, parameters:parameters) .response {
        (request, response, data, error) in   
    }    
}
```

The image is not nil. And I cannot find which value is actually nil.

Comment: Well, like it says, some of your variables/constants are nil. Is imageData nil? Its the only one you unwrap in your code here

Comment: You mentioned image is not nil, I assume you talking about the parameter image, please can you debug to find if imageData extracted from image is valid or a nil value. If that's the case, calling base64EncodedStringWithOptions on nil would cause the problem

Comment: The imageData is not nil :(

Comment: are you 100% sure? Have you added a `print` statement? Please include the exact line where it crashes instead of "only" giving the error message.

Comment: It prints this: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQgAAAEICAIAAAAslP2oAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAA
and goes on. It crashes exactly by the request here :   Alamofire.request(.POST, API_URL, parameters:parameters) .response {
        (request, response, data, error) in   
    }

Comment: What's happening in Alamofire ? And what's calling uploadImage, where is the image from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imageData is probably nil. Always do nil checks and avoid unwrapping.

```
func uploadImage(var image:UIImage) {
  if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image), let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([.Encoding64CharacterLineLength]) {
    let parameters = [
      "img": base64String
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, API_URL, parameters: parameters) .response {
      (request, response, data, error) in   
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: The imageData is not nil :( I checked it .

Comment: Well then you need to step through your code and check what is, set a breakpoint at the first line of this function and step through it.